# Pre-installed Windows; Drive Partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, preinstallation

I got a laptop with pre-installed windows 8.
I want to dual-boot Ubuntu on it.
The problem is that my laptop has only one drive(no partition).
How do i install Ubuntu without losing my pre-installed Windows and all the data stored.
Is there any way to make partition without having the risk of losing the windows data.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu installer should recognize your Windows 8 partition and offer to resize that partition to make room for Ubuntu. The only way to avoid any risk of losing your Windows data is to back it up, but the Ubuntu installation is very reliable at keeping Windows installations intact.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows 8 pre-installed it has UEFI. 
Also shows Windows 8 screens

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

If an Ultrabook you may also have RAID from Intel SRT which you have to turn off and remove the meta-data. After you install Ubuntu you can turn Intel SRT back on if you want the SSD used with Windows. If you install Ubuntu to SSD then you do not have the speed up in Windows but Ubuntu is faster.

Also if an Ultrabook you may need to use nomodeset if video is nVidia mode.

Samsung series 5 UltraBook, erase Windows & install to SSD

http://schoolsplay.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/install-ubuntu-linux-on-a-samsung-series-5-ultrabook-with-ssd/